# Console log is being doubled when selecting an option from a select element

Tags: javascript, html

So, I have this select element or dropdown menu. Whenever I select an option, it logged the text twice. My question is, how can I take the text once, whenever I chose an option.

```js
menuType = document.getElementById("menu-type");
menuType.addEventListener("click", function () {
  var option = menuType.options[menuType.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(option);
});
```

```html
<select id="menu-type">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `change` event instead of `click`.

```js
menuType = document.getElementById("menu-type");
menuType.addEventListener("change", function () {
  var option = menuType.options[menuType.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(option);
});
```

```html
<select id="menu-type">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
  <option>4</option>
</select>
```